# View not rendering when using Marker OnPress inside a Map View

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to have a view pop up on the map when I press on a marker. My code is as follows.

Here is my render method

```
return (
      <View styles={styles.container}>
        {this.state.error && (
          <Text style={styles.errorText}>Error: {this.state.error}</Text>
        )}
        {this.state.mapReady && (
          <MapView
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            ref={map => (this.map = map)}
            showsUserLocation
            style={styles.userMap}
            initialRegion={this.state.initialRegion}
          >
            {this.renderVendorMarkers()}
          </MapView>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

So far, this works great.  My map renders on my simulator screen and shows the current user location (based on accessing their location on their device.)  mapReady is just a property which I set to true when the user permits the use of his/her location data.

this.renderVendorMarkers is a method that does the following:

```
renderVendorMarkers = () => {
    const { vendorData } = this.state;
    if (vendorData) {
      return (
        <View>
          {vendorData.map((vendor, idx) => {
            return (<Marker
            key={idx}
            ref={ref => (this.state.markers[idx] = ref)}
            onPress={() => this.onMarkerPress(marker, idx)}
            coordinate={{
              latitude: marker.coordinates.lat,
              longitude: marker.coordinates.lng
            }}
          >
            <Callout>
              <Text>{marker.VendorName}</Text>
            </Callout>
          </Marker>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```

};

In this method, I take vendorData which is some fake array of vendor Objects with their coordinates and loop through each vendor (using .map).  I then generate all the markers on the map.  This all works as intended.  My map renders on the app screen and all the markers are shown on the map.  This is where I get stuck.

In my marker component within this method, I use onPress and link it to another method.

```
   onMarkerPress = (location, index) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.vendorContainer}>
        <Text>Vendor Data:{location.VendorName}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

What should happen here is every time I press on a marker, a box should show up near the bottom of my map with the vendor Name.  However, when I click on the marker, nothing shows up. I dont get any errors so I dont know if this code is incorrect or its a styling issue.  My styles are as follows:

```
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("screen");

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1 },
  vendorContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 100,
    width: 200,
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "white"
  },
  userMap: { height: height },
```

Comment: Any suggestions?  Ive tried everything.  The view isnt even rendering but I dont get any errors when I call on markerPress.  I updated the code above.